# PHP/MYSQL: Check whether email exists in database?

Tags: php, mysql

Having a bit of an issue validating the email address to check whether it exists in the database. It still submits the form. I don't know if it there is an issue with the query or if it just won't work. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

**CODE:**

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['reg']))
{
$email = $_POST['login_email'];
$checkqry = "SELECT * from clinic_receptionist WHERE recep_email = '$email'";
$checkresult = mysqli_query($conn,$checkqry);
if(mysqli_num_rows($checkresult) > 0)
{
    echo "THE EMAIL ADDRESS IS IN USE";
}
}
?>
<form action="create_profile.php" method="post">

    <label>Email Address</label>
    <input type="email" name="login_email" id="login_email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email Address" required oninvalid="setCustomValidity('Please enter your email address')">
    <label>Password</label>
    <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required oninvalid="setCustomValidity('Please enter your password')">


    <input type="submit" name="reg" value="Register" class="btn btn-primary" style="margin-left:6%;">
<div style=" margin-top:4%;">
    <a href ="index.php" target="_blank" style="margin-left:6%;">Already have an Account? - Login</a>
</div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Query should be like this:

```
$email = $_POST['login_email'];
$checkqry = "SELECT * from clinic_receptionist WHERE recep_email = '$email' ";
```

Comment: hi, it is still posting the code, to the next page. I have done an edit as well and included your answer in it.

Comment: `SELECT * FROM clinic_receptionist WHERE recep_email = 'test@gmail.com'` the result:  `Showing rows 0 - 0 (1 total, Query took 0.0005 seconds.)`

Comment: post your tables and all

Comment: `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS clinic_receptionist (
  recep_id int(50) NOT NULL,
  recep_username varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  recep_password varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  recep_salt varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  recep_full_name varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  recep_gender varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  recep_clinic_id int(50) NOT NULL,
  recep_address varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  recep_email varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  recep_mobile bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  recep_doj date NOT NULL,
  recep_dob date NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=29 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;`

THE TABLE STRUCTURE, do you need the values too?

Comment: check what comes in `$checkresult`?

Comment: `object(mysqli_result)#2 (5) { ["current_field"]=> int(0) ["field_count"]=> int(12) ["lengths"]=> NULL ["num_rows"]=> int(0) ["type"]=> int(0) }` I get this using `var_dump($checkresult)`
 and on `echo $checkresult` I get `Catchable fatal error: Object of class mysqli_result could not be converted to string in /usr/local/ampps/www/doctor/register.php on line 30`

Comment: print the result and debug it

Comment: Why am I getting no answer message which says email exists and why is it still submitting?

Comment: Hi I managed to fix it with further research, I guess something was wrong with my if else statement, Thanks for the help though :)